# Can I say 'This paper concludes by saying...'

Tags: grammar, sentence

Or does that look strange? I am looking for a way to not look too formal but still retain some professionalism.

Many thanks

Comment: 'Saying' is a strange report verb for a paper. I'd expect 'suggesting' / 'claiming' / asserting' ...

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a way to conclude your own paper (not entirely clear from the question), you can say

> In conclusion, *(message)...*

This is not overly formal, but surely professional.

Comment: Thank you. This will actually be in the introductory paragraph, so I probably couldn't get away with saying 'In conclusion'.

Comment: Is the first paragraph meant to be a kind of abstract?  You might want to say "we conclude" or "I conclude."  I think it's a little less formal but still professional.

Comment: If it's   in the abstract / introduction,  either "we conclude" as per Noah, or "this paper will show conclusively" .